# How can I force Inline::C to link to an older library?

Tags: c, perl, unix, linker, inline-c

I'm dealing with a Perl Module that is only compatible with an older version of a shared system library. It just so happens that I have the older version of the library on my system, but I can't figure out how to force Perl's `Inline::C` to link up with that older library without removing the current, up to date library.

I'm trying to use `Device::USB`, which is compatible with the system library `libusb 0.1`, but is *incompatible* with `libusb 1.0`. My system does have `libusb 1.0` *and* `libusb 0.1` installed, but `make test` consistently fails while attempting to install the `Device::USB` module. This failure seems to be caused by Perl linking to the `libusb 1.0` libraries instead of the `libusb 0.1` libraries.

In `/usr/lib` I can see that the specific version of `libusb` that I want to use (`libusb-0.1.so.4`) is in there. What do I need to do to link specifically to this library instead of the generic `libusb.a`? Edit `Makefile.PL`? Edit the `.pm` files? Pass additional switches to `make`?

I've been reading up on the linker, but this additional layer of `Inline::C` really obfuscates when/where the traditional tricks of `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/my_lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `-rpath`, etc. can be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the Inline::C configuration option [LIBS](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.48/C/C.pod#LIBS)? According to the documentation you should be able to specify your lib with complete path then.